# Rails create single record VS create multiple records PERFOMANCE difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance, activemodel

Is there speed difference between this methods? (POSTGRESQL)

First

```
products = [{...},{...},...]
products.each { |p|
  Product.create(p)
}
```

Second

```
products = [{...},{...},...]
Product.create(products)
```

Both methods for each record make two queries:

```
1) INSERT INTO "products" VALUES (..)
2) UPDATE "products" SET "updated_at"...
```

Comment: "Is there speed difference" - this is something you can __measure__ (and know for sure)

Comment: but if I were to guess, the second one is at least not any slower. And it has the potential to be much faster (if all product creations were to be executed in a single INSERT)

Comment: You seem to have a callback defined in your model that is causing a second update query. There should only really be a single insert query. This really has nothing to do with the first portion of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) is right: both queries are the same, and you can write custom SQL. This is only a local solution though.

But I've found `activerecord-import` [gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) that is doing the same – bulk objects import.

```
products = [{...},{...},...]
Product.import(products)
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be little to no difference in terms of performance between the two.

If you check [the implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L31) you can see that if you pass an array to `.create` it iterates through the array and calls `.create` for each element in the array.

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Persistence
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    module ClassMethods
      # ...
      def create(attributes = nil, &block)
        if attributes.is_a?(Array)
          attributes.collect { |attr| create(attr, &block) }
        else
          object = new(attributes, &block)
          object.save
          object
        end
      end
      # ...
   end
end
```

ActiveRecord does not actually implement mass inserts. By this I mean inserting multiple rows in a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO products (name, description) VALUES ('Soap', '100% whale based.'),('Shampoo', '...')
```

Which can be faster by an order of magnitude given enough records.

But you can write your own SQL to accomplish this:

```
class Product
  def self.mass_insert(attributes)
    values = products.map("(#{attributes[:name]}, #{attributes[:description]})").join(',')
    self.connection.execute("INSERT INTO products (name, description) VALUES #{values}")
  end
end
```

Note that this simple example does NOT sanitize the input and is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.